# Webflux Webclient re-try with different URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am using webclient for the rest call and what i need is, if the primary URL is failing for the n'th time do the next re-try on Secondary URL . Please find below sample code for the logic which i am using. But it seems we cannot change the URL once he `client` is created and even if i change the URL its not getting effected and still requests are been fired to the initial URL.

```
ClientHttpConnector connector;//initiate
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(connector).build();
WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec client = webClient.post();

client.uri("http://primaryUrl/").body(BodyInserters.fromObject("hi")).retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).retryWhen(Retry.anyOf(Exception.class)
                    .exponentialBackoff(Duration.ofSeconds(2), Duration.ofSeconds(10)).doOnRetry(x ->
                    {
                        if (x.iteration() == 2) {
                            client.uri("http://fail_over_url/");//this does not work
                        }
                    })
                    .retryMax(2)).subscribe(WebClientTest::logCompletion, WebClientTest::handleError);
```

Is there any way to change the URL at the middle of re-try cycle ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But it seems we cannot change the URL once he client is created

You cannot - it's immutable.

> even if i change the URL its not getting effected

You're not actually changing the URL. Take a look at the `uri()` method - it's returning a *new* instance with a URI set. Since you're not doing anything with that new instance, nothing happens (as expected.)

The route I'd probably suggest is to create a separate method to form & return your basic `WebClient` publisher:

```
private Mono<String> fromUrl(String url) {
    return WebClient.builder().clientConnector(connector).build()
            .post()
            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue("hi"))
            .uri(url)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class);
}
```

...and then do something like:

```
fromUrl("https://httpstat.us/400").retryWhen(Retry.backoff(2, Duration.ofSeconds(1)))
        .onErrorResume(t -> Exceptions.isRetryExhausted(t), t -> fromUrl("https://httpstat.us/500").retryWhen(Retry.backoff(5, Duration.ofSeconds(1))))
        .onErrorResume(t -> Exceptions.isRetryExhausted(t), t -> fromUrl("https://httpstat.us/200").retryWhen(Retry.backoff(7, Duration.ofSeconds(1))))
```

...which will try `/400` 3 times, then try `/500` 5 times, then `/200` up to 7 times (but unless it's down, that will of course return on the first try.)

*Note that the above example uses the latest version of reactor-core which has the retry functionality built in, rather than the retry functionality in reactor addons. Translating it to the reactor addons functionality should be reasonably straightforward.*

This doesn't not strictly changing the URL in the *same* retry cycle, but instead chaining requests together with configurable retries per request. This then allows you to set different retry strategies on different URLs, which is advantageous if you don't necessarily want the retry to "carry on" from its previous point (It could make sense to set the backoff back to one second for a fresh URL, for example.)

Comment: What version of Reactor + addons are you using? Tons of error in my ide for static reference and wrong method signatures. Also where is `connector` coming from in fromUrl, would it not need to be passed in, or are you assuming it is global in class?

Comment: @123 Latest version of reactor core - no need for add-ons anymore, contains all the retry stuff built in. (Assuming connector is global as the question doesn't instantiate it anywhere, but that's trivial to change if it's not.)

Comment: Ah, actually have both in test project. Looks like extras was first in the imports though, so needed full path. Also I think OP is still using extras though, since they use `anyOf`, which isn't in core `Retry`.

Comment: @123 Good point - that'll teach me for rushing... I'll clarify that in the answer.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelBerry , perfect answer.

Comment: I think I'll use this too but damn is there not any other way? CXF had the SequentialStrategy where you could specify many url alternatives and time between retries...